# Why ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')?

Tags: angular, typescript

Why the component is rendering correctly but the browser console throws this error?:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Thank you in advance! :)

member-profile.component.html:

```
  <div *ngIf="member">
  <div><img src="..\..\..\assets\images\avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:60px; height: 60px;"><h3>{{ member.name}} {{member.surname}}</h3></div>
  <div><i class="fas fa-user-tie"></i><span>Role: </span>{{ member.role }}</div>
  <div><i class="fas fa-at"></i><span>Email: </span>{{ member.email }}</div>
  <div><i class="fas fa-user-tag"></i><span>Username: </span>{{ member.username }}</div>
  <div>
    <i class="fas fa-brain"></i>
    <span>Skills: </span>
    <div id="Expert" *ngIf="expertList.length > 0">
      Expert
      <span *ngFor="let skill of expertList">
        {{skill.skill}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: please include complete code sample

Comment: Presumably `expertList` is `null`/`undefined`. Have you checked that it contains the data you expect?

Answer (score 8):

The error message

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

tells you that, at one point in time, the value of `expertList` is  `undefined`.

So, we can only assume but the probability is high that the value of `expertList` is loaded via an asynchronous call. That means as long as the call hasn't returned, the value of `expertList` stays undefined.

To get rid of the error you need to adjust the condition in your `*ngIf`.

```
<div id="Expert" *ngIf="expertList?.length > 0">
  ...
</div>
```

By adding a `?` the execution of the expression is stopped if a `null` or `undefined` value occurs, so the error message does not occur anymore. This is called optional chaining.

Answer (score 4):

It can be because `expertList` is not available when the component load. Do you fetch that value through HTTP or something?. If so you can do three things.

On your component's constructor, initialize the `expertList` variable with an empty array. `expertList = []`

You can have a variable `isLoad` that starts with `false` on the constructor and when the fetch end, becomes `true`. This variable should be used on the HTML.

```
<div *ngIf="isLoad">
    <i class="fas fa-brain"></i>
    <span>Skills: </span>
    <div id="Expert" *ngIf="expertList.length > 0">
      Expert
      <span *ngFor="let skill of expertList">
        {{skill.skill}}
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Or you can just check that `expertList` is not `undefined` (with the `?`).

```
 <div id="Expert" *ngIf="expertList?.length > 0">
      Expert
      <span *ngFor="let skill of expertList">
        {{skill.skill}}
      </span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Add "?" after expertList in ngIf.
It is mostly because initially the property expertList is undefined.
So it has not length property.
the operator "?" will return false instead of error if a variable is undefined

```
<div id="Expert" *ngIf="expertList?.length > 0">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting the `expertList` value from some subscription? Seems that your html is rendering faster than the sub return, so when it hits the check for `expertList.length` the `expertList` is probably not returned yet, effectively having nothing to check the .length of. Try with `*ngIf="expertList?.length > 0"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Property doesn't have the value, check property!=undefined before calculating length

at some point the property (property.length) is undefined.